# Calculate column in pandas based on values of other columns ( col3 = 1 if col1<col2 and col2 > col1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns CLOSE and EMA50.
If I plot them in a graph the values looks like:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUeAj.png)

Blue line represents column CLOSE and red line is EMA50.

Now I need to add another column called SIGNAL and the value of this column should be 1 only if CLOSE > EMA50 in present row but in previous rows CLOSE < EMA50.

Basically what I want is a signal when the CLOSE was smaller then EMA50 but then it was bigger than EMA50.

Until now I managed to do this:

```
my_query_index = source_data.query('CLOSE < EMA50').index
source_data.loc[my_query_index,'SEMNAL_INITIAL_LONG'] = 1
```

which gives me a signal that CLOSE got smaller than EMA50 but now I don't know how to calculate when CLOSE > EMA50 and in previous rows I had CLOSE<EMA50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shift`:

```
df['SIGNAL'] = (
        df['CLOSE'].gt(df['EMA50'])
        & df['CLOSE'].shift().lt(df['EMA50'].shift())
    ).astype(int)
```

```
>>> df
   CLOSE  EMA50  SIGNAL
0   10.5   12.1       0
1   11.3   12.2       0
2   12.2   12.4       0
3   13.9   12.8       1  # Here (CLOSE > EMA50) & (CLOSE-1 < EMA50-1)
4   14.1   13.3       0
```

Comment: @Lapoco. Is it what you expect?

Comment: thanks, looks good but I had to modify a little bit the function: I had to extend my condition CLOSE<EMA50 and to say that also CLOSE>EMA150 and SEMNAL_UNGHI =2.0. I combined all those in another column called SEMNAL_INITIAL_LONG.
So i adjusted your code to source_data['SIGNAL'] = (
         source_data['CLOSE'].gt(source_data['EMA50'])
        & source_data['SEMNAL_INITIAL_LONG'].shift().eq(2)).astype(int) 
My df looks like https://i.imgur.com/ZClY8jh.png but what is strange is that on plottly I see 2 lines for each signal: https://i.imgur.com/Uw9PKI4.png In excel is looking good